# How can show values in bar - GoogleChart/SQL

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I need to put the values ​​inside the bar or outside it but I need you to show me the value, I've already seen some examples but the arrays tables have more than one line with the values ​​placed in the hand, but mine connects by SQL

How can I place the values ​​on my bar chart?

**A user showed me this answer, but in "var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable"
It returns the values ​​in the rows**

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Descr', 'Downlink', 'Uplink'],
        ['win7protemplate', 12, 5],
        ['S60', 14, 5],
        ['iPad', 3.5, 12], ]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/heennkkee/rekso9t6/

**But mine only has 1 line per account that pull this value from MySQL**

```
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["barchart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       ['quantidade_demanda','COUNT(Subclasse)'],

 <?php 

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(Subclasse), Subclasse AS quantidade_demanda FROM demandas_portal WHERE Categoria = 'Demanda Ambiental' GROUP BY Subclasse";



 $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){

 echo "['".$row['quantidade_demanda']."',".$row['COUNT(Subclasse)']."],";
 }
 ?> 

        ]);
```

**Would I have to add a new variable? because I only have these options**

```
var options = {
    colors: ['#00544d'],
    width: 500,
    height: 250

  }; 

        options.legend = 'none';

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_demanda'));
    chart.draw(data,options);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are referring to displaying annotations on the bars,
you need to add another column to the data table,
using an annotation role...

add the annotation role to the column heading, here...

```
  ['quantidade_demanda','COUNT(Subclasse)', {role: 'annotation', type: 'string'}],  // <-- add annoation role to column heading
```

then repeat the column value as a string, here...

```
echo "['".$row['quantidade_demanda']."',".$row['COUNT(Subclasse)'].",'".$row['COUNT(Subclasse)']."'],";  // <-- add value of annotation, repeat column value as string
```

see following snippet...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['quantidade_demanda','COUNT(Subclasse)', {role: 'annotation', type: 'string'}],  // <-- add annoation role to column heading

  <?php
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(Subclasse), Subclasse AS quantidade_demanda FROM demandas_portal WHERE Categoria = 'Demanda Ambiental' GROUP BY Subclasse";
    $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
      echo "['".$row['quantidade_demanda']."',".$row['COUNT(Subclasse)'].",'".$row['COUNT(Subclasse)']."'],";  // <-- add value of annotation, repeat column value as string
    }
  ?>

]);
```